# What does 'in one's sum' mean exactly?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

have been reading a [long essay on psychology](https://books.google.com/books?id=1-5vp3zM6HEC&pg=PA158&lpg=PA158&dq=%22We%20seek%20to%20test%20and%20find%20ourselves%20in%20the%20intimacy%20of%20the%20therapeutic%20relationship,%20to%20become%20known%20to%20and%20accepted%20by%20the%20other,%20in%20whose%20sum%20we%20may%20more%20fully%20assess%20ourselves%22&source=bl&ots=RSmAhH0KQX&sig=ACfU3U3jjGETyVtd0O7hzf6X54UYK91RZA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjFluuPx7frAhVNh-AKHZs8C-IQ6AEwAXoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22We%20seek%20to%20test%20and%20find%20ourselves%20in%20the%20intimacy%20of%20the%20therapeutic%20relationship%2C%20to%20become%20known%20to%20and%20accepted%20by%20the%20other%2C%20in%20whose%20sum%20we%20may%20more%20fully%20assess%20ourselves%22&f=false) and, at some point, the authors use the phrase "in one's sum", whose meaning I could not catch. I looked it up at some dictionaries, but I could not find either the phrase or a possible meaning for it. The context is as follows:

“We seek to test and find ourselves in the intimacy of the therapeutic relationship, to become known to and accepted by the other, **in whose sum** we may more fully assess ourselves.”

and

"**In their sum**, we can then most fully assess our potential for life."

Can anyone help me understand this phrase?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide a link or reference to the essay, or more surrounding context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Sum* might be used here in two different ways:

- *Sum* meaning summation, esteem or estimation. "Accepted bu others," implies we wish to be esteemed, valued, by others.
- *In their sum,* most often means "in all its parts," though in the cited paragraph, it might also mean "in their [others] esteem".

To me, this reading is somewhat obscure and infelicitous. In an attempt to seem erudite, the author chose rather unclear usage. Perhaps it could be summed more succinctly,

```
Therapists view their own worth by the evaluation of others.
```